# Wordpress: NextGen Plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this website: http://www.princeslick.com/?page_id=28 and I have installed the nextgen plugin on it, the gallery is not working as it should. Why is it not similar to this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/faq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NextGen CSS file is not being included at the top of your page, so your images are not being styled at all. It should be included when the wp_head() function runs. Reinclude that if it is not there, or link the CSS file directly.

Comment: @Nick Pyett shouldn't this be done automatically by the plugin?

Comment: Yes, but this should happen when wp_head() runs. If they have taken this out of the header.php file in their template, then this can't happen. If you view the source, there is no generator meta tag, which is included with the wp_head().

Comment: @Nick Pyett - I built this theme myself, I didn't know about this, so in future I should build the themes using the header files as it should.

Comment: Easily done. Removing either the wp_head() or wp_footer() can easily break a theme. If you are using WP3 you should also consider copying the functions.php from the TwentyTen theme, as it has some quite useful functions in there.

Comment: @Nick Pyett Yes I am using the default functions from twenty ten. So all i need to do is include the wp_head() funtion? so plugins can automatically import the needed files?